# Parse RestSharp Post Response To Get Content Of Specific XML Tag

Tags: c#, xml, post, restsharp

I am trying to take the content of a specific tag from the XML document I get in response to a post request made using RestSharp as follows:

```
//Post the xml and receive an xml response

public static string xPostXml(this string destinationUrl, string xml)
    {

        var client = new RestClient(destinationUrl);
        var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
        request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        request.AddParameter("undefined", xml, ParameterType.RequestBody);


        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {

            return response.Content;
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write(string.Format("{0}({1})", response.StatusDescription, response.StatusCode));
        }
        return null;
    }

//parse the xml into tags to evaluate the content of one

public string AResponseIndicatingTheCalcIsWorkingCorrectly()
        {
            var result = this.endpoint.xPostXml(this.requestXml);
            var doc = XDocument.Parse(result);
            var answer = doc.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "Income");
            var myElement = doc.Descendants("Income").FirstOrDefault();
            var income = XElementExtension.InnerXML(myElement);
            return income;


        }
```

However, this does not work because the xml is returned as follows:
`<Result>k__BackingField":{"<Income>k__BackingField":14800.8,"<Investment>k__BackingField":499850.0,"<PricingVersion>k__BackingField":{"<EffectiveDate>k__BackingField":null,"`

and so on

Using another method the Xml was returned like this(not from the start but can see the different tag format), which was successfully parsed by the above method:

```
<Income>14800.8</Income><Investment>499850</Investment><PricingVersion><EffectiveDate xsi:nil="true" /><Version>v1137</Version></PricingVersion><MortalityMethod>HRe pos</MortalityMethod>
```

So I either need to be able to produce the second example of xml output, or parse the first example and look at a specific tag each time.

Thanks:)

Edit:

My friend below informed me this is a Json string so I have tried to parse it as follows:

```
    public string doStuff(string xml)
    {
        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(xml);
        return data.Income;


    }
```

Is returning null though.
I am calling this method in the method AResponseIndicatingTheCalcIsWorking and returning doStuff(xml).

Comment: The curly brackets indicate you got a JSON string and not an xml string.

Comment: ok thanks well I tried:

Comment: public string doStuff(string xml)
        {
            dynamic data = JObject.Parse(xml);
            return data.Income;
            

        }

Comment: 1) Can you provide a [mcve] that reproduces your problem -- compilable code  + **complete, well-formed** XML -- so we can test and resolve your problem?  2) Can the rest API you are calling be modified to return cleaner XML?

Comment: Hello. It's difficult to provide the xml in its full form because it is sensitive potentially. Ultimately I just need a way to either: (1) Return an XML string instead of a JSON string (the method AResponseIndicating... works fine if I use non-restsharp code aka if the string is returned as an XML string as shown in the second bit of xml/json I have linked)

Comment: or (2) I need a way to parse the JSON string and get the contents of one of the tags from it